# Transform dictionary key-value pairs to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dic = {'contig_100003': ['contig_14576'],  'contig_100022': ['contig_96468'],  'contig_100023': ['contig_24939', 'contig_33444', 'contig_72441']}
```

And I would like to get a list (including the key) of it:

```
List = [(contig_100003','contig_14576'), (contig_100022','contig_96468'), (contig_100023','contig_24939', 'contig_33444', 'contig_72441')]
```

However, my code cannot get rid of the internal/value list:

```
list(dic.items())
[('contig_100003', ['contig_14576']),
 ('contig_100022', ['contig_96468']),
 ('contig_100023', ['contig_24939', 'contig_33444', 'contig_72441'])]
```

Answer (score 4):

This might solve it

```
[(k, *v) for k, v in dic.items()]
```

Comment: ```[(k, *v) for k, v in dic.items()]```

Comment: Can I add a string to each "v"? This works for "k" (">" + k), but cannot find a way to do it for "v".

Answer (score 3):

You can use tuple concatenation to get the desired output:

```py
result = [(key,) + tuple(value) for key, value in dic.items()]
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[('contig_100003', 'contig_14576'), ('contig_100022', 'contig_96468'),
('contig_100023', 'contig_24939', 'contig_33444', 'contig_72441')]
```